# What kind of supervised model to use when I have vectors as input and vectors as output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am making a project in which I have to predict a plane trajectory.
I have 2 types of trajectory, the first one is the planned, and the second one is the real one that I recovered after the end of the flight.

The two trajectories are (x,y) points on a map and I want to predict the real one with the planned one.

What kind of model do you use? I heard about multivariate regression or recurrent neural network but I am not sure about both, I think multivariate is not appropriate and rnn include time as parameter and I would not want to use it first.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: can you provide few more details about the problem statement ??

Comment: What kind of information do you want to know ?

Comment: what you are predicting here, the points on a plane or the plane itself whether it is real one or not?? dimensions of the plane ?? what are the input features , etc.

Comment: For now, i would only want to take as input the planned trajectory and predict the real with it, trajectory are often the same and i think i can get something with that.

For example, i have a plane wich have to passed on the points :
(0,0) ; (1,1) ; (2,2) 
This is its planned trajectory.
After the fly, we collect the real trajectory and we get : 
(0,0) ; (1.5,1.5) ; (2,2)

I want to predict the real with the planned as input

Answer (score 0):

You could try either training single-target multiple regression models, and predict the *x* and *y* variables independently. The other way to go about is to use multi-target regression-based methods. The most commonly used method using Predictive Clustering trees. You can read about various methods from https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-models-with-multiple-target-variables-8baa75aacd to start with. I hope it is somewhat helpful. :)